# Минимизация функции Розенброка методом Ньютона — C++

Tags: c++

Нужно методом Ньютона минимизировать функцию Розенброка

[image: f(x,y)=100\cdot(x-y^2)^2+(1-y)^2]

Критерии останова: `e = 0.1, 0.01, 0.001`. Есть код для этого, но не знаю как его применить к функции Розенброка (проблема с матрицей Якоби)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int n = 2;
    double x[n];
    const int shag = 40;
    int iter;

    int i, j, k;
    double tmp;
    double fvec[n];
    double p[n];
    double fmatrix[n][n];

    double e;
    std::cout << "Vvedite e" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> e;
#define stream cout

    x[0] = 10;
    x[1] = 30;

    for (iter = 1; iter <= shag; iter++) {
        stream << "\n " << iter << " iteraciya";

        stream << "\n\nInfo: Vektor x:";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            stream << "\nx[" << i << "] = " << x[i];

        fvec[0] = 2 * x[0];
        fvec[1] = 2 * x[1];

        tmp = 0.;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            tmp += fabs(fvec[i]);
        }
        if (tmp <= e)
            break;

        fmatrix[0][0] = 2;
        fmatrix[0][1] = 0;
        fmatrix[1][0] = 0;
        fmatrix[1][1] = 2;

        stream << "\n\nInfo: Vectornaya matrica x:\n";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                stream << fmatrix[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            stream << "\n";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] = -fvec[i];
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            tmp = fmatrix[i][i];

            if (tmp == 0.) {
                stream << "Error: Nulevoy element v matritse\n";
                return 0;
            }

            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                p[j] -= p[i] / tmp;
                for (k = n - 1; k >= i; k--) {
                    fmatrix[j][k] -= fmatrix[i][k] * fmatrix[j][i] / tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            tmp = 0;
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                tmp += fmatrix[i][j] * p[j];
            }
            p[i] = (p[i] - tmp) / fmatrix[i][i];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            x[i] += p[i];
        }
    }
    if (iter < shag) {
        stream << "\n\n Minimum \n";
        stream << "(" << x[0] << ", " << x[1] << ")\n";
        return 0;
    }
    stream << "\nError: Maksimalnoe chislo iteracii\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод Ньютона ищет корни системы уравнений, больше он ничего не делает. Для минимизации же функции этот метод применяют к системе уравнений, в которой частные производные по всем аргументам равны нулю. Эта система, в свою очередь, выражается из исходного уравнения, для которого мы ищем минимум.

Проблема в том, что в случае вашей функции эта система не имеет решения (точнее, решений бесконечно много), а метод Ньютона для этого не приспособлен.

Вот так выглядит сама функция:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно попытаться отлавливать это вручную, ориентируясь на изменение производных, но вообще для таких случаев есть другие методы.